# something wrong when navigating from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have one activity and 3 fragments **A,B,C** when app starts it holds main **Fragment A** then from **Fragment A** i'm navigating to **Fragment B** and from **Fragment B** to **Fragment C**. Code works and it opens **Fragment C** from **Fragment B**, but first it opens **Fragment A** and just then **Fragment C**. Why and how can I fix this? Do I need one more activity to host Fragments B,C?

**Method which switches fragments:**

```
    private Fragment contentFragment;
     public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate());
        if (fragment != null){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment,tag);
            if (!(fragment instanceof FragmentB)){
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            transaction.commit();
            contentFragment = fragment;
        }
    }
```

**R.id.content_frame** is id of Layout which is used on activity **setContentView**.

Comment: All you need to switch Fragments is the FragmentTransaction and the replace method. So, maybe start commenting out that back stack stuff and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're popping all fragments in back stack before replace current fragment with the next one.

You don't need this line:

```
while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate());
```

Also, this part is pointless:

```
if (!(fragment instanceof FragmentB)){
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
}
transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
```

because the last line ignores condition.

If you wish to add fragments to back stack except `FragmentB`, then try to edit your code next way:

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
        if (!(fragment instanceof FragmentB)){
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        contentFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```